# zend framework 3 - get urlencoded route param which has a space

Tags: parameters, routes, urlencode, zend-framework3, php-7.1

I have the following segment route in Zend Framework 3:

```
'route' => '/search/:query'
```

In the controller, I get the query like this:

```
$query = $this->params()->fromRoute('query');
```

I've noticed that this does not work for queries which include a space. For both of the following URLs, the query is retrieved as `foo+bar`.

```
https://www.example.com/search/foo+bar
https://www.example.com/search/foo%2Bbar
```

However, the first query should be interpreted as `foo bar` instead of `foo+bar`.

For the time being we are using a workaround that parses the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly:

```
$queryEncoded = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2];
$query        = urldecode($queryEncoded);
```

Does Zend Framework 3 offer a native way to properly retrieve the `query` parameter in this case?

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing Route parameters and segments.

Below examples of 2 Routes, one Literal, one Segment:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'users' => [
            'type'          => Literal::class,
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options'       => [
                'route'    => '/users',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => UserIndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'child_routes'  => [
                'view' => [
                    'type'          => Segment::class,
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'options'       => [
                        'route'       => '/:id',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ],
                        'defaults'    => [
                            'controller' => UserViewController::class,
                            'action'     => 'view',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                // more routes
            ],
            // more routes
        ],
    ],
],
```

So here we have Routes:

- "users", translated to `/users` in the URL (Literal)
- "view", translated to `/:id` in the URL (Segment)

The latter is a segment. It's also got some constraints: it must be any number of just numbers.

So we have users (index) and specific view (view) by id. Example URL's:

- example.com/users
- example.com/users/12
- example.com/users/123

Note, because it's part of the defined route and defined in constraints, you would get the `id` given in these examples in a controller like so:

```
$id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);
```

This gives you the `id` passed in the route or a `null` value.

What you're attempting in your question is something for a conditional view or search or something. You want parameters. You want:

- example.com/users?role=admin

This gives you a `key` "role" with the `value` "admin". In the context you would want to show all of the users with the role admin.

You do not define key/value types in your routes. It's simply not necessary. Zend Router makes sure that all of the ones given in a Request are prepared for you to use using:

```
$queryParams = $this->params()->fromQuery('role', null);
```

Notice the change of `fromRoute` to `fromQuery`! Everything after `?` is query. Zend Router prepares these for you to use by the key name; `role` in this case.

The preparation of query keys/values also takes spaces into account. If you had the following URL:

- example.com/users?foo=space%20bar&role=admin

You would have the following results:

```
$foo  = $this->params()->fromQuery('foo', null);   // "space bar"
$role = $this->params()->fromQuery('role', null'); // "admin"
$test = $this->params()->fromQuery('test', null'); // null
```

Comment: Thank you, however we do not want to use a question mark in the URL. For example, we want our URLs similar to Techcrunch's search results: https://techcrunch.com/search/hello%20world

Comment: That's when you must define your Route variables, like `/path/:variable1/:variable2/:variable3` and get them with `$this->params()->fromRoute('variable1', null)`. Parts defined like so: `/hello` are part of the pre-defined path. Parts defined like so `/:var` (notice the colon char) are parts defined as variable. Example is the `/:id` in the answer.

Comment: ... which is exactly what I wrote in the first four lines of my original question.

Comment: "[..] queries which include a space" <-- Query !== Route ... `/route/literal` & `/route/:segment` - Both of these are **route**, *not* **query**. In the URI a "query" comes AFTER the route, after the `?`. A query is NOT part of the route definition. Hence also the difference in functions: `from**Query**` and `from**Route**`. See the bottom of my answer where I give you `from**Query**` examples, so strings *WITH* space char.

Comment: You're confusing search query with query string.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-16 -> see the image. Route === path, query === query. At least, according to the RFC spec.